# Is it possible to put data in widget before build?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a system that sends 2 things in order:

1. sends info on what widget to build (Label, text input, button, etc)
2. sends data to be inserted into the widget (label text, text input hint text, etc)

the issue is from what I know about flutter, I couldn't add data in after I made the widget, before building (I think globalkey for the state only works AFTER the widget is built)

does anyone know if it's possible to put the data into the widget that's already defined before build?
I can send some code if anyone requests it but this is a general question.

Example:
(I build the widget using widgetListData (the individual data isnt known yet))

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    List<Map<String, dynamic>> widgetListData = [
      {
        "WidgetType": "TextField",
        "ButtonText": "Account Receivable",
        "Position": "New",
        "ID": "text_textfield"
      }
    ];
    List<Widget> widgetList = createWidgetList(widgetListData, passData);
    return SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: const Text("Menu"),
          ),
          body: SingleChildScrollView(
              child: Column(
            children: widgetList,
          ))),
    );
  }
```

in the actual app, the widgetListData will come from a List of actions, the first one being this create widget action, and the second one being display/ put data

the code i showed will be done first as it is the first element of the action List like so:

```
List<Map<String, dynmaic>> actionList = [
    {"Type": "CreateWidget", "Content": ...},
    {"Type": "PutData", "Content": ...}
]
```

the put data action will be processed AFTER i finished creating the widgets, but before I build them.

Comment: can i get a code snippet

Comment: share some workflow about what you want to achieve ... sorry but question is not very clear right now

Comment: please add a code snippet of what you need

Comment: I have added code snippets and what I want to achieve, please ask for more info if you need it.

Answer (score 0):

Create a class which will take 2 parameters (1. Widget type, 2. Widget data). Based on the widget type create widgets and add data into that widget. For example you get widget type text then return a widget `Text('$content')` or if you get widget type button then return `MaterialButton(child:Text(content), onPressed(){})`.

Comment: Instead of passing widget type, you can simply pass the whole widget itself along with the required data :)

Comment: I have updated my question, the data comes after the widget creation, so I dont have `content` when Im making the Text widget, for instance

Comment: Keep it empty till you get the content and update widget once you get the content